# Ruby on Rails - what is make method on a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

In my lib/tasks/data.rake, I have User.make(attributes). The make method appears to create a new record, but I cannot find any docs on this. The make method is not defined by my User model and fyi  my User model inherits ActiveRecord::Base.

Comment: `data.rake` isn't something Rails creates; it's presumably part of *your* code. So maybe it just doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I 'called a friend', it turned out to be https://github.com/notahat/machinist gem