# Capybara - Undefined method make

Tags: rspec, capybara

Trying to get started with Capybara and have a pretty much straightforward test:

```
require 'spec_helper'

    describe 'the login process', :type => :feature do
      before :each do
        User.make(:email => 'example@example.com', :password => 'password')
      end

      it 'signs them in' do
        visit '/sessions/new'
        within("#session") do
          fill_in 'Login', :with => 'example@example.com'
          fill_in 'Password', :with => 'password'
        end
        click_link 'Sign in'
        page.should have_content 'Signed in successfully.'
      end
    end
```

I seem to be getting the following error: [Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0oQ4.png). Any ideas what exactly would cause this. I have Capybara included in my gemfile:

```
group :development, :test do
   gem 'rspec-rails'
   gem 'factory_girl_rails'
   gem 'pry-debugger'
   gem 'quiet_assets'
   gem 'capybara'
end
```

And have set it up correctly in my `spec_helper.rb`

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'
require 'capybara/rspec'

Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false
  config.order = "random"
  config.include Capybara::DSL

  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
end
```

So what could exactly be causing this error when I run `bundle exec rspec spec/requests/user_test.rb`

Comment: Why do you use `User.make(...)`? Can you use `User.create(...)` instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14451397/ruby-on-rails-what-is-make-method-on-a-model), it appears that the `make` method is from the machinist gem. Make sure you have it included in the Gemfile. Or you can use `User.create`.